# Computing equivalent vector of random variables from covariance matrix

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Given a covariance matrix, how can I construct a vector of expressions of randomly distributed variables whose covariance matrix is equal to the given one?

EDIT: All variables are normally distributed.

I have an algorithm that gets the covariances correct, but not the variances on the diagonal:

```
a = [0]*len(r)
for x, row in enumerate(cov_matrix(r)):
    for y, item in enumerate(row):
        if x > y: continue
        v = noise(math.sqrt(abs(item)))
        a[x] += v
        if item > 0:
            a[y] += v
        else:
            a[y] -= v
```

I feel like this should be simple ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is your target covariance matrix and $LL^T = A$, and $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is a vector of independent random variables with mean zero and variance 1, then $y = Lx$ has the required covariance. Here $L$ is a matrix and $L^T$ is its transpose. $L$ can just be the Cholesky factor of $A$. ((Check: $\mathrm{cov}(y) = E[yy^T] = E[(Lx)(Lx)^T] = E[Lxx^TL^T] = LE[xx^T]L^T$ (by linearity of expectation) $= L\mathrm{cov}(x)L^T = LIL^T = LL^T = A$. $\mathrm{cov}(y) = E[yy^T]$ because $y$ has mean 0, and likewise for $\mathrm{cov}(x)$.)

That's not too far from a "complete" solution, actually. If you start with a vector $y$ of random variables with mean zero and covariance matrix $A$, then if $A = LL^T$ and $x = L^{-1}y$, then $\mathrm{cov}(x) = I$. That doesn't necessarily imply that the components of $x$ are independent; it means they are uncorrelated. So the most general construction is to begin with a vector $x$ of *uncorrelated* random variables with mean zero and variance 1 and let $y=Lx$. (I only mean that every example can theoretically be obtained that way, not that it's necessarily the best or most computationally efficient way to do it.)

Comment: It depends on what you are doing.  Say you want uniformly distributed random variables with a particular correlation structure.  You can't just generate uncorrelated uniform random variables and apply the Cholesky decomposition because a sum of uniform random variables is no longer uniform. It will have the correct correlation (as you show) but the marginal distributions will not be uniform.

Comment: The way I understood the problem, the only goal is to produce a random vector with a prescribed covariance matrix. If more information is prescribed, like the marginal distributions of the components, then I don't know if my method can be extended. 

Answer (score 2):

This question is perhaps more suited to [stats exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  Darsh suggested using the Cholesky decomposition, but this only works if the distribution of the random variables you want to generate is Gaussian. Otherwise there are two techniques that I know of, the [Iman-Conover method](https://web.archive.org/web/20180508044702/http://www.mynl.com:80/pptp/Correlation_CAS_052004.pdf) and the methods based on [Copulas](http://www.springerlink.com/content/r20lu6631v34j876/).

Comment: "Using [...] Cholesky decomposition [...] only works if the distribution of the random variables you want to generate is Gaussian": No (re-read Darsh's comment).

Comment: @Didier: See my comment on Darsh's answer.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.